Need help understanding mapOrAccumulate() in Kotlin Arrow
I'm working on some code using Kotlin and arrow-kt that repeatedly calls a function and collects the results. I found a function in arrow-core called mapOrAccumulate() that seems like the correct tool for the job. To try it out, I whipped up a simple demo function and some tests. My demo code looks like:
fun checkAllEven( inputs:List<Int>): Either<NonEmptyList<Throwable>, List<Any>>
    {
        return inputs.mapOrAccumulate<Throwable, Int, Any> {
            println(it)
            checkEven(it)
        }
            
    }

fun checkEven( value:Int):Either<Throwable, String>
    {
        if( value % 2 != 0 )
        {
            return Either.Left( Throwable( "${value.toString()} not even!"))
        }
        else
        {
            return Either.Right("${value.toString()} even")
        }
    }

I then test it using:
@Test
fun testMapOrAccumulate()
{

    val inputs = listOf(0,1,2,3,4,5)

    checkAllEven(inputs).fold({
        println("left: $it")
    },{
        println("right: $it")
    })
}

My expectation was that it would put the 'failures' into the left and the 'successes' into the right. Instead, everything is ending up as one big list in the right and my output is:

right: [Either.Right(0 even), Either.Left(java.lang.Throwable: 1 not
even!), Either.Right(2 even), Either.Left(java.lang.Throwable: 3 not
even!), Either.Right(4 even), Either.Left(java.lang.Throwable: 5 not
even!)]

What am I missing here? There is clearly something I'm not understanding.

I'm not familiar with Arrow, but your code doesn't at all seem similar to examples in docs for the mapOrAccumulate function. You return an either, they return the right value directly and use functions like bind, raise, etc. to provide errors.

You need to bind the result of checkEven in the mapOrAccumulate function:
fun checkAllEven( inputs:List<Int>): EitherNel<Throwable, List<String>>
{
   return inputs.mapOrAccumulate {
      println(it)
      checkEven(it).bind()
   }
}

The bind will return the right value of the either. In case a left value is encountered an error will be raised and accumulated.
With this change the output looks like this:
left: NonEmptyList(java.lang.Throwable: 1 not even!,
  java.lang.Throwable: 3 not even!, java.lang.Throwable: 5 not even!)

You can find more details in the Arrow documentation
